# Identify this ceiling drywall technique

Tags: drywall, ceiling

Can anyone identify the technique used for this ceiling? I originally thought knock down, but the more I read, the more unsure I become.
There is the odd “sharp” point, but only the odd one. The valleys aren’t very deep, thus my original knockdown thought. [image]

Comment: Where in the world are you? In the UK that would just be called 'artex', which though a brand name is also a simple technique that produces that random peaked texture - simply rollered on. See https://designingidea.com/ceiling-texture-types/ [though they don't have a picture of artex, it looks like your picture].

Comment: Thanks for that link. I’m Canada, but the 70s is possibly correct for the age. Although it could be the trowel method in there.

Comment: My ex-father-in-law [plasterer by trade] used to proudly announce that he spent the 70s being paid a fortune to put up artex for people too lazy/incompetent to do it for themselves, then the entirety of the 80s & 90s taking it off again ;)